# 500 Server Error on WS call after SQL Server Upgrade, 403 error when accessing directly

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services

Last night my server admin upgraded us to SQL Server 2008, this morning I made the updates to our code to reflect the new server location in both my DBML as well as my webconfig.  Running locally everything looked good, I migrated to my development server and once there our very first web service call started to fail with a '500 Internal Server Error'.  The message returned when looking in firebug is simply:

```
"{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}"
```

Also when I attempt to just navigate to my web service directly in my browser it is giving me a 403 error.  No firewall settings on my web-sever have changed to my knowledge the only known change is the SQL server upgrade.

I can't really come up with any reason why this would happen after a sql server change.  Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2008 did you upgrade to? The reason I ask is because TCP connections are disabled by default in Developer/Evaluation and Express editions? Also are you using a named instance?

Comment: Not sure what edition it is, I'll try to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try checking the port you are connecting to.

I had this problem a few weeks ago where my admin upgraded and changed the port from the default `1433` to a different one.

Just a thought, hope this helps.

Comment: Good guess, they did change my port and didn't let me know.

Comment: +1: Those silly IT people... always going around and changing stuff. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything else: Connect to the new server using Management Studio on your machine (not from the sql server itself).

If this works, then look at your connection strings on your dev server to ensure they are correct.

If it doesn't work, go sit at the DBA's desk and kindly ask them to finish the server configuration.  Namely: enabling TCP.